# select substring of column returns null and empty

Tags: mysql, substr

I'm having trouble using mysql's `substr` function.

my query is:

`SELECT distinct(substr(col1,0,10)) from table;`

The results returned are `NULL` and an empty row.

Am I using `substr` incorrectly, or can I not use `distinct` or a column name?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, the position of the first character of a string is 1, not 0; this should fix it:

```
SELECT distinct(substr(col1, 1, 10)) 
FROM `table`
```

Secondly, your table contains at least one row in which `col1` is `NULL`. For those rows, the result of `SUBSTR` is `NULL` as well.

Comment: thanks jack! i missed that sentence on position=1, but it's clearly in the documentation. you saved the day again!